# How to show that $x > \sin x \cdot (\cos x)^4 $ (without using graph)?

Tags: inequality

How to show that $x > \sin x (\cos x)^4 $ for $x \in (0, \pi/2) $ (without using graph)?

Comment: This is false for $x=0$. $0\not>0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true if $x>0$, but not if $x\le 0$.

If you know the two inequalities
$$
\begin{align}
x & > \sin x \\
1 & \ge (\cos x)^4
\end{align}
$$
then you can multiply the two left sides and multiply the two right sides.  Exercise: Figure out which parts of this don't work if $x\le 0$.

Comment: Of course! :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

It holds for $x>0$; it follows as a result of the inequalities $x > \sin(x)$ (which holds for $x>0$) and $ |\cos(x)| \leq 1$ (which holds on $\mathbb{R}$). As ALexR says, the inequality doesn't hold for $x=0$, and for $x < 0$, the inequality is reversed.